# How search a text file after scanning with zxing?

Tags: java, android, arrays, search, zxing

After zxing scans a barcode how do I get it to search for a barcode saved in a text file saved in the raw resources folder? Do these need to be separate activities? I feel like this is a simple task. I have the scanner working perfect I am hung up on how to compare scan result with txt file.

```
  @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "cancelled");
            Toast.makeText(this, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "scanned");
            Toast.makeText(this, "scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);

    }
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(R.raw.upc);
        int len = 0;
        byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];
        while (-1 != (len = in.read(data1))) {

            if (new String(data1, 0, len).contains(result.getContents()))
            //do something...
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to achieve. Are you saying you want to compare the contents of a scanned barcode with the contents of a some known fixed barcodes you bundle as a resource?

Comment: Yes I have a txt file with barcodes only and when the barcodes is scanned, compare the scanned barcode with the text file to see if it is present

Comment: at the end of mainactivity Instead of "scanned" or "cancelled" on Toast, change to "yes" or "no" if the scanned barcode is in the txt file or not.

Comment: What answer are you hoping for? You want us to give you a piece of code that does it all? You are still not asking a specific question on a single problem, you are asking for a entire code project. My answer would be: "learn java"

Comment: Thanks roy! lol I am learning everyday! I have everything working as far as the scanner scanning. I have a txt file in my res. I was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: My problem is: How do I integrate my txt file into the zxing activity?

Comment: Get the resource ID, and either read it in and compare raw, or turn it into a class of some sort if you need a proper `.equals()` implementation. The details for each are too involved for a simple Q&A. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html